# Thumbnail effect like google chrome website screenshot

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, effect

Could anyone show me how to make a thumbnail with hover effect like google chrome tab website thumbnail e.g. when you hover the website screenshot image, a blue box will appear with pin and you can move.

THank you

Comment: Could you please make that a little clearer? I'm not understanding your question...

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. I can't edit OPs, so here's a translation: In the Google Chrome browser, when you open a new tab, you will see a list of thumbnails of your most visited sites. When you hover over one of those, an animation appears above the thumbnail with a "pin" and an "x", which either pin the site to this list, or removes it. What popoxinhxan wants to know is how would you replicate this on your website.

Comment: Also, he wants to be able to move the thumbnails around.

Comment: jchapa, you are right, your explanation is better

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's [hover](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover#overout) event to provide the highlight effect, call `setTimeout` inside of it to slide up the top bar a little bit later, and call `clearTimeout` on that timeout in the unhover.

You can use jQuery UI to allow dragging; see [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any existing code that will do this out of the box but you can use JQuery UI sortable to drag/drop a list of box elements (including images) per this demo:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid